# bearer token in Twilio webhook

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp, twilio-api, bearer-token

Im setting up a Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp
for when a message comes in I set a webhook to my application’s link.

But my application requires a bearer token.

How can I set up twilio to send our bearer token together with the request it makes to my URL?

thank you

i make all test without the bearer token and it works fine.
but to go live, we need this token autentication for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webhook just triggers a GET or POST request to the registered URL, as you rightfully said. To be able to add custom parameters, such as a bearer token, you need to add an intermediate step in between. This can be achieved, for example, with any Serverless function.

Naturally, using [Twilio Serverless](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/api-request) would be the easiest option to do this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  // Create a new voice response object
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  try {
    // Open APIs From Space: http://open-notify.org
    // Number of people in space
    const response = await axios.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json`,
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${request.body.token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
    });
    const { number, people } = response.data;

    const names = people.map((astronaut) => astronaut.name).sort();
    // Create a list formatter to join the names with commas and 'and'
    // so that the played speech sounds more natural
    const listFormatter = new Intl.ListFormat('en');

    twiml.say(`There are ${number} people in space.`);
    twiml.pause({ length: 1 });
    twiml.say(`Their names are: ${listFormatter.format(names)}`);
    // Return the final TwiML as the second argument to `callback`
    // This will render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
    // and result in the message being played back to the user
    return callback(null, twiml);
  } catch (error) {
    // In the event of an error, return a 500 error and the error message
    console.error(error);
    return callback(error);
  }
};
```